# How to show a data from two different database (mongodb) in separate html card in site?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I try to create web site  which will contain ads that users place on the site. I create a database with mongodb, one database contain a images and others database contain text, I create a "seacrets" page when a users login they can add images from computer and text and that will bi store in database. I managed to do it but i dont now how to present images and text from database in html card for each input individually.

This is my app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const saltRounds = 10;
const multer = require("multer");

const app = express();



app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
const db1 = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/SiteofAds",);
const db2 = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Images",{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
const db3 = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Content",);

const UsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  email: String,
  password: String,

});

const User = db1.model("User", UsersSchema);

const ImageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    image: {
        data:Buffer,
        contentType:String
    }
});

const Image = db2.model("Image", ImageSchema);

const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({storage:storage})

const ContentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String

});

const Content = db3.model("Content", ContentSchema);


images= []
contents= []
app.get("/", async (req, res) =>{
    const images = await Image.find().sort({_id:-1})
    const contents = await Content.find().sort({_id:-1})
    res.render("home", {images: images, contents: contents});
});

app.get("/login", function(req, res){
    res.render("login");
});

app.get("/register", function(req, res){
    res.render("register");
});



app.post("/register", function(req, res){


    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
        const newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.username,
        password: hash
    });

    newUser.save().then(function(){
        res.render("secrets");
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
        
        
    });


  
});


app.post("/login", function(req, res){
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;


    User.findOne({email:username}).then(user => {
        if (user) {
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, result) {
        if (result === true) {
            res.render("secrets");
        }
    });
        }
    })

})

myTextArea = "";
img = "";


app.post("/secrets", upload.single("image"), async(req, res) =>{
    

    const image = new Image({
        image:{
            data: req.file.buffer,
            contentType: req.file.mimetype
        }
    })

    const content = new Content({
        text: req.body.myTextArea
    })

    await image.save();
    await content.save();

    res.render('home');  

})

app.get("/contact", function(req, res){
    res.render("contact");
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
    res.render("about");
});

app.get("/proba", function(req, res){
    res.render("proba");
});


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

this is my home.ejs

```
<%- include("partials/header") %>



<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="images/NoImage.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h1 class="card-header">No.1</h1>
                <p slass="card-text">
                    Text
                </p>
                <button class="button2"> About</button>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I found how to pull out data from database with foreach, but i dont now how to data present in individually card.

I try this, but all data from database display on same space in one card.  I try put this for loop outside car but i didn't succed.
Can anyone help me or have any ideas, thanks

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="card">

            <% if (images.length> 0) { %>
                <% images.forEach((image)=> { %>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img
                            src="data:<%= image.image.contentType %>;base64,<%= image.image.data.toString('base64') %>" />
                    </div>
                    <% }); %>
            <% } else { %>
                    <p>No images uploaded yet.</p>
             <% } %>

                        <div class="card-content">
                                <h1 class="card-header">Oglas br.1</h1>
                                <p slass="card-text">
            <% if (contents.length> 0) { %>
                <% contents.forEach((content)=> { %>
                                <div>
                                    <h2>
                                        <%= content.text %>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                <% }); %>
            <% } else { %>
                                <p>No content yet.</p>
             <% } %>
                                    
                                <button class="button2"> Detalji</button>
                        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To find a solution for problem.

Answer (score 0):

When retrieving data from a database (via fetch), storing the result in a useState array, in which you can then use the `array,map` to cycle through each item in the array.

Further note, creating a component and passing the data via props may prove valuable for your needs.

As an example:

`const [data, setData] = useState() // useState - defaulted to empty.`

Then use fetch to retrieve the data via await.
Store that awaited result into a variable and console.log the resulting variable to ensure you're getting the data.

After which, use your useState via `setData(passing in your awaited variable)`

Then in your JSX you can create a div, which then maps the result.

```
div className = "container">
     {data.map(item => {
         return (
          <NewComponent data={item}/>
         )
}})
</div>
```

Then your new component can access each element in the new component via props.

Hope this helps.